# How to quantify the differencen between 2/4 and 20/40?

Tags: statistics, statistical-inference, machine-learning

Assume I have two methods to do prediction. The first method makes 4 predictions and 2 out of 4 are correct. The second method makes 40 predictions and 20 out of 40 are correct. The prediction precisions of both methods are the same, which is 2/4=20/40=0.5. But I think the second method is better than the first one, because it makes more correct predictions. Is there a measure to quantify this? Any suggestion may help:) Thanks in advance.

Comment: If your measure of goodness is purely the number of correct predictions, why would you bother to compute the fraction of correct predictions in the first place?

Comment: @MPW I think he wants a measure that considers both the number and the fraction.

Comment: this question should be discussed in any text on statistical-inference (be it Baysian or not).

Comment: @MPW I want to consider both, because just consider the correction predictions is not enough. For example, one method makes 21 correct predictions via 100000 predictions, which is considered as a bad method.

Comment: I may be wrong, but isn't this what p-values are for?

Comment: @IttayWeiss Not Bayesian, just need a criterion to evaluate different methods.

Comment: *the second method is better than the first one, because it makes more correct predictions* -- however, it also makes more incorrect predictions.

Comment: I think you need to specify what do you mean by better. You gave the second method more chances to make correct predictions, so it is not strange that it made more correct predictions.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

We want to estimate the probability of success when we make a prediction.  We are using the estimator $S/N$, where $N$ is the number of trials and $S$ is the number of successes. In the case you describe, both estimates are $\frac{1}{2}$.

However, the **variance** of the estimator when $N=40$ is $\frac{1}{10}$ times the variance when the estimator is based on $N=4$. Or equivalently the standard deviation of the estimator when $N=40$ is $\frac{1}{\sqrt{10}}$ times the standard deviation when $N=4$. The estimate based on $40$ trials is more reliable than the estimate based on $4$ trials. Variance (or standard deviation) is a way of quantifying *how much* more reliable.

Comment: How to compute the variance?

Comment: There are quite a number of technical details.  If the true probability of success is $p$, and we make $N$ trials, then the variance of the estimator $S/N$ is $\frac{p(1-p)}{N}$. But there are additional related concepts such as sample variance. And I have not described at all how the variance can be used to find the probability that your estimate (here $1/2$), is within a specified distance of the truth. Very big subject, that takes several weeks of an introductory statistics course to begin to describe.

Comment: It's worth specifically emphasizing that the reliability in this answer is not the reliability of the prediction methods - it's how reliably we know the reliability of the prediction methods. The lower variance in the second case doesn't tell us anything about which predictor is better.

Comment: @user2357112 agree!!!